# Flutter splash view

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm quite new to Flutter.

I'm trying to develop a splash view. In this widget I would like to check stored authentication and then redirect to home page (NavigationHomeScreen) or to login page (SignInView). I'm using Bloc pattern.
My doubt is if is better something like this with MaterialPageRouter or assigning the new page to a variable and then show widget variable in BlocBuilder's builder.

1:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is SessionOK) {
              Navigator.push<dynamic>(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => scaffoldSafeAreaBuilder(
                    child: const NavigationHomeScreen(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
              BuildContextProvider()((context) => context.loaderOverlay.hide());
            } else if (state is SessionKO) {
              Navigator.push<dynamic>(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                  // builder: (BuildContext context) => const LoginPage(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => const SignInView(),
                ),
              );
              BuildContextProvider()((context) => context.loaderOverlay.hide());
            }
          },
          builder: (BuildContext context, AuthState state) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Image.asset(
                  "app_logo".toPng,
                  height: context.dynamicHeight(0.2),
                  width: context.dynamicWidth(0.9),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

2:

```
class _SplashViewState extends State<SplashView> {
  late final AuthBloc authBloc;

  Widget page;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    page = Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Image.asset(
                  "app_logo".toPng,
                  height: context.dynamicHeight(0.2),
                  width: context.dynamicWidth(0.9),
                ),
              ),
            );

    print("splashview initState");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is SessionOK) {
              setState(() {
                page = const NavigationHomeScreen();
              });
              BuildContextProvider()((context) => context.loaderOverlay.hide());
            } else if (state is SessionKO) {
              setState(() {
                page = const SignInView();
              });
              BuildContextProvider()((context) => context.loaderOverlay.hide());
            }
          },
          builder: (BuildContext context, AuthState state) {
            return page;
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Option 1 would be the recommended one. You must treat Login Page & Home Page as a screen. So ideally you should transition to a new page based on the logic.

Comment: in option 1 remove the first Bloc Builder it is unnecessary